# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorization')

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, sequelize.js

This is my code

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const userRepository = require("../repositories/userRepository");
const SALT = 10;

async whoami(req, next) {
    const bearerToken = req.headers.authorization;
    const token = bearerToken.split("Bearer ")[1];
    const tokenPayload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SIGNATURE_KEY || "Rahasia");

    req.user = await userRepository.find(tokenPayload.id);
    next();
},
```

This is the controller

```
whoami(req, res) {
    authService
        .whoami(req.body)
        .then((user) => {
            res.status(200).json(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(422).json({
                status: "FAIL",
                message: err.message,
            });
        });
},
```

Comment: You're only passing `req.body` to `whoami`, not all of `req`.

Comment: what i change to get this req.headers.authorization; ?

Comment: I think `.whoami(req)`. But where is the `next` argument in that? Maybe I don't understand how the first code is related to the controller.

Comment: I think, the request body don't have the Authorization property, so what you need to do is, While calling the API, you need to add the Authorization property on the request header

Answer (score 1):

```
//change whoami to look like this

whoami(req, res) {
    authService
        .whoami(req) //req instead of only request body
        .then((user) => {
            res.status(200).json(user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(422).json({
                status: "FAIL",
                message: err.message,
            });
        });
},
```